# Affinetransform center scale coordinates

Tags: java, math, scale, affinetransform

I have a graphics.drawImage with a buffer that I want to draw center scaled and a Rectangle with the coordinates and scale I want the buffer to be drawn as.

```
tr2.translate(buffer.getWidth()/2, buffer.getHeight()/2);
tr2.scale((double)rect.width/buffer.getWidth(),(double) rect.height/buffer.getHeight());
tr2.translate(-buffer.getWidth()/2, -buffer.getHeight()/2);
```

The question is what do I need to do to get it aligned to the rectangle coordinates?

The buffer coordinates should be mapped to rect loaction.

So if the top left corner of rect is (30,80) we want buffer top left corner after the scale to be also (30,80)

The problem is if before the scale the top left corner was (0,0) now it is something like(-15,10) depending on the scale which we need to find.

Comment: How is the `Buffer` positioned on the coordinate grid? If its top left corner is on the origin then I think your two `translate` calls should be switched to get it back to that position.

Comment: The problem is once it's scaled the corner changes.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I.e. give a simple set of coordinates for `Buffer` and `Rect` (using upper-case names for variables is confusing!) and then state which points should be mapped to which by this transformation.

Comment: @andrix89 Yes, so I assume that your first translate is meant to get the `Buffer` centered on the origin, then scale, then move back. I thought you were translating in the wrong direction, but I realise now it's the `Graphics` that is moving, not the `Buffer`. Doesn't the scaling mean that the move back (the second `translate`) should be wrt the scaled distance though? In any case, example coordinates as @MvG suggested would help understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

- The top left corner of a `BufferedImage` starts at (0,0), which simplifies things.
- When you add an operation to `AffineTransform`, it places it in the *front* of the queue. (I know there isn't really a queue, see below.) If you add a translation, then add a scale, then filter your data, your data will look as though it was filtered *and then* translated.

If you think in matrices, it would look like this:

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
```

You now have an empty identity matrix (a no-op):

[A0] = [I]

```
at.translate(x, y);
```

Now you've added a translation:

[A1] = [I][tr] = [tr]

```
at.scale(x, y);
```

And then a scale:

[A2] = [A0][sc] = [tr][sc]

So when you filter your data (points are in columns) you get:

[new] = [A2][old] = [tr][sc][old] = [tr][scaledVersion]

Here's an example:

```
static String backgroundFilename = "green.png";
static String foregroundFilename = "red.png";

public static void drawImageInRectangle(BufferedImage src, BufferedImage dst, Rectangle rect) {
    if (dst == src) {
        src = new BufferedImage(src.getColorModel(), src.copyData(null), src.getColorModel().isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
    }
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    // AffineTransform applies transformations in the OPPOSITE ORDER to how they were added
    at.translate(rect.x, rect.y);
    at.scale((double)rect.width/src.getWidth(), (double)rect.height/src.getHeight());
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(at, new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC));
    op.filter(src, dst);
}

static Rectangle getCenterRectangle(BufferedImage image) {
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    return new Rectangle(w/4, h/4, w/2, h/2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundFilename));
    BufferedImage foreground = ImageIO.read(new File(foregroundFilename));
    drawImageInRectangle(foreground, background, getCenterRectangle(background));
    ImageIO.write(background, "png", new File("output.png"));
}
```

output.png:

[image: output]

**EDIT:**

- Rereading the question, I see that I was mistaken about what you were trying to do: You are drawing onto a `Graphics2D`, not onto another `BufferedImage`. Sorry. The easiest solution then is to just use `Graphics2D.drawImage` and specify the target rectangle. Be sure to `setRenderingHint` first.
- It doesn't matter where the origin is when something is scaled, so long as the appropriate translation is done afterwords.

Consider these two **equivalent** functions:

```
public static AffineTransform longWay(BufferedImage buffer, Rectangle rect){
    AffineTransform tr= new AffineTransform();
    AffineTransform tr2= new AffineTransform();
    tr.translate(
            rect.x+(rect.width-buffer.getWidth())/2,
            rect.y+(rect.height-buffer.getHeight())/2); 
    tr2.translate(buffer.getWidth()/2, buffer.getHeight()/2);
    tr2.scale(
            (double)rect.width/buffer.getWidth(),
            (double)rect.height/buffer.getHeight() );
    tr2.translate(-buffer.getWidth()/2,-buffer.getHeight()/2);
    tr.concatenate(tr2);
    return tr;
}

public static AffineTransform shortWay(BufferedImage buffer, Rectangle rect){
    AffineTransform tr = new AffineTransform();
    tr.translate(rect.x, rect.y);
    tr.scale((double)rect.width/buffer.getWidth(), (double)rect.height/buffer.getHeight());
    return tr;
}
```

If you doubt that they're the same, remember that an `AffineTransform` is just a list of 6 `double` values, and try this:

```
System.out.println(longWay(buff,rect));
System.out.println(shortWay(buff,rect));
```

Output:

```
AffineTransform[[0.5, 0.0, 32.0], [0.0, 0.5, 24.0]]
AffineTransform[[0.5, 0.0, 32.0], [0.0, 0.5, 24.0]]
```

Comment: Yes but the problem is it doesn't scale centrally, which is what I want and why this is a problem to begin with, otherwise I could just use the drawimage scale.

Comment: Your solution inspired me to find the real solution.

Comment: You realize that there's no difference between scaling toward the center and just translating after scaling, right? The two are equivalent.

Comment: From what I have seen they aren't.They transform the coordinates themselves.

Comment: I see, I thought it was scaling with an offset.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to  use 2 transforms.

```
AffineTransform tr= new AffineTransform();
AffineTransform tr2= new AffineTransform();
```

One handles the translation and the aligning.

```
tr.translate(rect.x+(rect.width-buffer.getWidth())/2,
rect.y+(rect.height-buffer.getHeight())/2);
```

And the other handles the center scaling.

```
tr2.translate(buffer.getWidth()/2, buffer.getHeight()/2);
tr2.scale((double)rect.width/buffer.getWidth(),
(double)rect.height/buffer.getHeight() );
tr2.translate(-buffer.getWidth()/2,-buffer.getHeight()/2);
```

We then concatenate it like this.

```
tr.concatenate(tr2);
```

And use the tr for the drawing.

```
gfx.drawImage(buffer, tr, null);
```

Concatenate seems to keep `AffineTransform` separate so as to not affect each other.

You can probably make the scaling anchor arbitrary if you revise the math at `tr.translate`